# Is ‘the’ always necessary in such structures?

Tags: articles, definite-articles

> 1. For qualitative measures, we have to consider **the** place of Korean
>    universities in global rankings, as well as **the** global rankings of
>    Korean journals.

Is the ‘the’ necessary in all expressions/phrases which are in the form of “the ———— of ————“? Is there such a rule?

Other examples:

> 2. He contributed to **the** imposition **of** such regulations.
> 3. We should not overlook **the** place **of** religion in this society.
> 4. People often disregard the functions of rituals in this culture.

So the question is about the necessity of *the* when it comes with *of* in such linguistic structure. Can we say that *of* make our word (such as place, imposition, rankings in the above examples) require definite article. Can we say it defines the word? Could ‘the’ be omitted in the above examples? What if the word is plural for example in *rankings* and *functions* in the examples mentions above.

As to above examples, I personally feel like I can omit the ‘the’ in 2 and the second one in 1. Am I right?

Comment: Omitting them would make you sound like a non-native speaker.

Comment: **the x of y** is very common in English. [People often disregard, **no s**//defines, not definitize]

Comment: @Lambie So is it like a rule? ‘the’ is necessary?

Comment: It's just standard English definite vs indefinite articles: "A bag of apples"/"The bag of apples".

Comment: @StuartF So there should be either ‘a’ or ‘the’ when the word is singular, and we can omit ‘the’ when it is plural. Is this correct as a rule?

Comment: There is no rule which means that *the* must be used in such constructions (although  there's really not one construction there, but many, each with different restrictions). However, the semantic function of the *of*-PP is often to restrict our understanding of the identity of the first noun phrase. In other words it helps us 'determine' the identity of the first NP. Thus the *of*-PP often works just like a genitive Determiner. Genitive Determiners usually construe definiteness, and so their phrasal genitive counterparts usually require *the*. But this is not a rule. (cont)

Comment: Not every *X of Y* construction should be thought of as a phrasal genitive. For example *a bag of apples*, cannot be thought of *apples' bag.* Executive summary: no, but there's a strong tendency for them to do so.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe in the first sentence, the second the could potentially be omitted because it refers to a plural (?)... Otherwise: the articles are needed because they refer to specific things.

It's true to too many repetitions of "the" sound clunky, though.

*He contributed to the imposition of such regulations.*
Maybe rephrase this to "He contributed to **imposing** such regulations"
Nouns describing actions (nominalization) can sound awkward in English: verbs usually sound more natural, nouns more formal).

*We should not overlook the place of religion in this society.*
Maybe better: **Religion's place** in this society(?).

*People often disregard**s** the functions of rituals in this culture.*
**Disregard** (plural). "People" is a notional plural in English (more than one person), never singular.
The function of ritual **are often disregarded** in this culture (?).

Answer (score 1):

For the first sentence, only the first "the" is needed. The other three sentences are correct.  The reason why Sentence 1 is incorrect is as follows: In Sentence 1, there are two uses of the word "the" Number 1: "Consider the place." Number 2: "As well as the global rankings," which really means, "Consider the global rankings." Now, to determine if the "the" is needed, remove all adjectives and articles. Now, we are left with "Consider place" and "Consider rankings." The former is not grammatically correct, so a "the" must be added, but the latter is grammatically correct. so it can be left as-is. I hope that helped!

Comment: Why is only the first "the" required in the first example?

Comment: In sentence one, there are two uses of the word "the"  Number one: "

Comment: In Sentence 1, there are two uses of the word "the"  Number 1: "Consider the place."  Number 2: "As well as the global rankings," which really means, "Consider the global rankings."  Now, to determine if the "the" is needed, remove all adjectives and articles.  Now, we are left with "Consider place" and "Consider rankings."  The former is not grammatically correct, so a "the" must be added, but the latter is grammatically correct. so it can be left as-is.  Did that clear it up?

Comment: You should edit any information needed to understand an answer into the answer itself. Comments can be deleted and the information in them can be lost